# Use selenium to enter password on website that has virtual keyboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am using selenium to log in to a website. But when it arrives on the password page the site asks to enter through a virtual keyboard and the send_keys command does not work.

CODE:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Página 1
chrome = wd.Chrome(executable_path='R:\\USUARIOS\\YVieira\\chromedriver.exe')
chrome.get('https://extranet.btgpactual.com')
user=chrome.find_element_by_id('txtLogin')
user.send_keys('yan.vieira')
user.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(3)
#Página 2

senha=chrome.find_element_by_id('txtSenha')
senha.send_keys("pssw")
```

HTML CODE:

```
<input type="password" id="txtSenha" name="txtSenha" maxlength="100">
```

[image]

Comment: Please share HTML code as text, code you tried and errors you got

Comment: try to enter the value using virtualKeyBoard loginKeyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use JavaScript to set value:

```
password = "pssw"
senha=chrome.find_element_by_id('txtSenha')
chrome.execute_script(f"arguments[0].value='{password}'", senha)
chrome.find_element_by_id("btnValidate").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function that would go through each letter of your password like (since the virtual keyboard - as per your screen-shot - is a sort of div elements each of which has `key` attribute having the value corresponding to the key value of the keyboard element)

```
passwd = "my pass"
for key in passwd:
  chrome.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@key="' + key + '"]').click()
```

which would just click corresponding divs on the page.

P.S. - this simple example is aassumed to work with simple passwords which do not require `shift` the key value